# Javascript Illustrator CS6, Regex doesn't match final substring

Tags: javascript, regex, adobe-illustrator

I have:

```
var columnNames = splitString[0].match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
```

I know splitString[0] is the string: "Name,Type,Cost,Water,Description"
However, columnNames becomes an array with:
Name,Type,Cost,Water

Using https://regex101.com/ it should be matching all 5 strings between the commas, but it does not. Missing the last one. Any idea why?

Note, adding a , at the end correctly matches all 5.

Edit: To clarify, this is Illustrator CS6 javascript.
If I run in a script:

`alert("Name,Type,Cost,Water,Description".match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g));`

It displays: Name,Type,Cost,Water

Comment: `const splitString = ["Name,Type,Cost,Water,Description"]; var columnNames = splitString[0].match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g); console.log(columnNames);` seems to give the correct output.  Are you sure there isn't other relevant code?

Comment: Please link to your saved regex101 that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It matches all 5 [here](https://regex101.com/r/siSjew/1)

Comment: In Illustrator CS6, if I add in a script:

`alert("Name,Type,Cost,Water,Description".match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g));`

It displays: Name,Type,Cost,Water

Comment: Yeah my issue @Barmar, is that is should match according to the regex sites, but in Illustrator Javascript CS6 it does not.

Comment: @dave, this is specifically for illustrator CS6 javascript. That does not give the correct output, no other change in code.

Comment: If the problem is specific to a product like that, you should say so in the question.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `.split(",")`?

Comment: @Barmar, yeah I realised and edited the question. And yes because I need it to ignore commas between "". Like a standard CSV reader. Note, I have a workaround which is just to add a , to the end of each line, but would be qurious why REGEX is different in this product.

Comment: I'm not sure, I suspect CS6 is using an old JavaScript engine with bugs in lookahead.